# What's the point of the Quad Rocket alt-fire?

Tags: titanfall

I'm at Gen 4 so have to use the Quad Rocket to head to 5, and I have no clue why anyone would ever use the alt-fire (zoom) mode.  The rockets simply seem to travel slower, and in a larger spread.  Against ground targets they smear out and maybe one rocket will hit near a grunt, and against Titans they become extremely easy to dodge.

Is that it, or is there some other subtle effect I'm not picking up on?  In what situations is the alt-fire mode advantageous?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think that's the point: you can make a narrow cone of denying fire at medium range, plus you can reload while then slower rockets are still travelling ─ basically you can block a titan-width corridor. No-one can enter without getting hit, and travel towards you will get them pummeled with rockets.

This has some defensive use. Not much, I admit, but I think that's the point of the mode.

Comment: Note that while this Gen 4 requirement sucks, it's not even close to the pure suck of the number of goosed pilots required at Gen 5 (i.e. shoot them out the air while invisible and ejecting)

Answer (score 0):

Yup, Quad Rocket's alternate slow-moving fire mode is all about blocking a path. Can be useful when defending an objective or when collaborating with other teammates.  This site has some useful tips on how to use the Quad Rocket, too: http://titanfall.onegameguide.com/quad-rocket/

The Quad Rocket isn't my favorite gun, but if you have to use it for the regen, the Stryder is the way to go.

Comment: It is preferable to summarize the main points of the link you posted in the answer, in case the site becomes unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that when you fire a couple rounds and then a couple in alt-mode, it can deal much  more damage than than usual. using it at close range is also a good idea because you can maneuver away from the blast spread.